# Giving names to polylines in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, labeling, line

Is it possible to give names to the polylines in ArcGIS 10.3?

what is the name of the tool?

Comment: Can you provide additional details? Do you have these names in a table? Do you want to provide random name identifier?

Answer (score 2):

There's no specific tool required. You need to have information in the **attribute table** of your polyline layer. This information will then be displayed should you configure the **labeling options** of the layer.

- Where to find the attribute table ?

Right click on your layer and select open attribute table. If necessary, add a field and some data.

[image: attribute table]

[image: add field]

- Where to find labeling options ?

Right click on your layer and select properties. In the lable tab,  choose your data field and set up options if necessary.

[image: labelling]